# Duality in Chebychev approximation

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

I got messed up with this problem and can't find any clue to solve this. Hope some one here can help me.

> > Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix an let $b$ be a vector in $R^{m}$. We consider the problem of minimizing $||Ax - b||_{\infty}$ over all $x \in R^{n}$. Here $||.||_\infty$ is the vector norm defined by $||y||_\infty = max_{i}|y_{i}|$. Let $v$ be the value of the optimal cost.
> >     
> > Let $p$ be any vector in $R^{m}$ that satisfies $\sum_{i=1}^{m}|p_{i}| = 1 $ and $p^{T}A = 0$. Show that $p^{T}b \le v$. Here $x,p,b$ is column vectors.

I really appreciate if some one can help me. Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest starting with the cases $m=2$ or $m=3$. Draw some pictures.

Comment: Oh really. I think the specific value of $m, n$ here is not important. I got stuck about how to transform the primal problem to linear programming form and get the proper dual problem, but the absolute expression $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{|p_{i}|}$ drives me crazy.

Comment: The truth of the result may not depend on the value of $m$. But your ability to visualize the problem probably does.

Comment: Can you make it clearer? I represent some cases in coordinate system but can't find any clue...

Answer (score 0):

#### Duality in Chebychev approximation

Consider the problem of minimizing $\| Ax−b \|_\infty$ over all $x \in R^n$. It is equivalent to the following LP:

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\operatorname{minimize} & t \\
\text {subject to } & -t \mathbf{1} \preceq A x-b \preceq t \mathbf{1}, \; t \geq 0
\end{array}
$$

with variables $x \in \mathrm{R}^n, t \in \mathrm{R}$. Where $\mathbf{1}$ denotes a vector with all components equal to one. To derive the dual problem, introduce Lagrange multipliers $\lambda , \mu \geq 0$ and we obtain the Lagragian:

$$
L(x, t, \lambda, \mu) = t + \lambda^T(-t \mathbf{1} - Ax + b) + \mu^T (Ax - b - t \mathbf{1})
$$

Thus the dual function is:

$$
g(\lambda, \mu) = \inf_{t \geq 0, \, x} L(x, t, \lambda, \mu) = \inf_{t \geq 0, \, x} (1 - \lambda^T \mathbf{1} - \mu^T \mathbf{1})\,t + (-A^T \lambda + A^T \mu)^T x + b^T(\lambda - \mu)
$$

Hence, we obtain the dual problem:

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\operatorname{maximize} & b^T (\lambda - \mu) \\
\text {subject to } & (\lambda + \mu)^T\mathbf{1} \leq 1 \\
  & A^T (-\lambda + \mu) = 0
\end{array}
$$

Let $y = \lambda - \mu$, since $\lambda, \mu \geq 0$, we have $|y| = \lambda + \mu$. $\;\;$ ($\lambda, \mu$ can not be both positive due to complementary slackness.)

The problem above turns into:

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\operatorname{maximize} & b^T y \\
\text {subject to } & \sum_{i} |y_i| \leq 1 \\
  & A^T y = 0
\end{array}
$$

Here we notice that the dual of minimizing an infinite norm is also a LP with 1-norm constraint.

Comment: (1) Why cannot $\lambda$ and $\mu$ both be positive? I cannot derive this from the complementary slackness. (2) How did you get rid of the $\lambda \geq 0$ and $\mu \geq 0$ condition in the dual problem? Thanks a lot.